# Dynamic columns in SSRS which depends on the data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have two tables as below.

```
Vehicle  Brand    Acquired Year 
A001     Toyota    2018            
A002     BMW       2019
A003     Honda     2019

Vehicle     Maintenance Year     Maintenance Cost
A001            2018                5000
A001            2019                7000
A001            2020                3000
A002            2020                8000
A003            2019                3000
A003            2020                2000
```

I would like to have a report like this:

```
Vehicle     Brand     Acquired Year     2018     2019     2020     
A001        Toyota        2018          5000     7000     3000
A002        BMW           2019           0         0      8000
A003        Honda         2019           0       3000     2000
```

Where the columns after the first three columns are dynamic and depends on the Maintenance Year in table 2. The data for those columns are the Maintenance Cost for the corresponding Maintenance Year.

Can someone provide some guides on this?

Comment: SSRS offers a [Matrix component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) to handle that for you.

Comment: @DaleK I have read it. btw for my report, do i need to set a row for the matrix ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "set a row" but you are going to group your rows by Vehicle, Brand & Acquired Year. Then create columns by Maintenance Year / Maintenance Cost.

Comment: May I know how to create column dynamically? There will be year 2021, 2020 and so on. I can get the Maintenance Year by `SELECT DISTINCT MAINTENANCE_YEAR FROM table2` @DaleK

Comment: You don't need to create the columns in SQL, the SSRS matrix will do it for you

Comment: Google SSRS Matrix Tutorial

Comment: But for my case, the first few columns can be done in a normal table, only the columns (for maintenance year) need the SSRS matrix?

Comment: Well you've tagged reporting services, so I am assuming you building a report, in which case let SSRS do the hard work for you. Else you have to build a dynamic pivot which is complex - why reinvent the wheel? Its not a trivial problem.

Comment: As Dale has tried to explain, just create a dataset query that has the columns Vehicle, Brand, Acquired Year, Maintenance Year, Maintenance Cost . Based on your sample data you will have 6 rows. Drop a matrix into the report, set row group to group on  Vehicle. Brand and Acquired, set column group to group on Maintenance year and drop cost into the data cell. That will give you what you want

Comment: @AlanSchofield How can I create the query from Maintenance Year dynamically?

Comment: I don't think you understand how the Matrix works, I'll post a full answer shortly.

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question? if so please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your sample data with the following dataset query.

```
DECLARE @v TABLE(Vehicle varchar(10), Brand varchar(10), [Acquired Year] int)
DECLARE @m TABLE(Vehicle varchar(10), [Maintainence Year] int, [Maintainence Cost] int)

INSERT INTO @v VALUES
('A001', 'Toyota', 2018),
('A002', 'BMW', 2019),
('A003', 'Honda', 2019)

INSERT INTO @m VALUES
('A001', 2018, 5000),
('A001', 2019, 7000),
('A001', 2020, 3000),
('A002', 2020, 8000),
('A003', 2019, 3000),
('A003', 2020, 2000)

SELECT 
    v.Vehicle, v.Brand, v.[Acquired Year], m.[Maintainence Year], m.[Maintainence Cost]
    FROM @v v 
    JOIN @m m on v.Vehicle = m.Vehicle
```

This gives us 6 rows in total to the output from the dataset looks like this..

```
Vehicle Brand   Acquired Year   Maintainence Year   Maintainence Cost
A001    Toyota  2018            2018                5000
A001    Toyota  2018            2019                7000
A001    Toyota  2018            2020                3000
A002    BMW     2019            2020                8000
A003    Honda   2019            2019                3000
A003    Honda   2019            2020                2000
```

**Note:** We do NOT need to do anything dynamic here, the report's matrix control will do that for us, if the number of years increases, so with the number of columns in the report without us having to do anything.

Create a new report.
Add a new dataset and set the dataset query to the script above or something that gives you the same layout of results from your actual data.

Add a matrix control to your report then

- Drag Vehicle from your dataset field list to the 'Rows' placeholder
- Drag Maintenance_Year to the 'Columns' placeholder
- Drag Maintenance_Cost to the 'Data' Placeholder

[image]

- Next, right-click the Vehicle text box and choose "Insert column => Inside Group - Right", then click the new cell and choose 'Brand' from the list

[image]

- Repeat with Acquired Year. When you do this, as Year is numeric, SSRS will add a SUM expression, you need to change this. Right click the expression and change it from

`=SUM(Fields!Acquired_Year.Value)`
to
`=FIRST(Fields!Acquired_Year.Value)`

The final design should look like this.

[image]

When we run the report we get this.

[image]